# Azure storage CRUD through java

Tags: java, spring, rest, azure

I am trying to create an application with java (for main logic) and spring (to create the api) and want to create, update and delete the files from an Azure storage account.

Please provide the suitable information.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to some tutorials about Azure Storage usage for Java as below.

1. [How to use Blob storage from Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage)
2. [How to use Queue storage from Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-queue-storage)
3. [How to use Table storage from Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage)
4. [How to use File Storage from Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage)

And there are these sample codes about Azure Storage for Java, please see [github.com/Azure-Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=storage&type=&language=java) and [Azure Code Samples](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/?platform=java&service=storage).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to take a look at the [Azure libraries for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/) or the [Azure Storage Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/).

Comment: Thank you, can you please provide me reference to write services in java without REST please?